# Bass.dll не воспроизводится сохранённый wav файл

Tags: delphi, аудио, bass.dll

Записываю звук с микрофона в TMemoryStream. Воспроизведение из потока выполняется нормально. Однако при сохранении в файл не воспроизводится ничего. При этом данные в файл пишутся.

Код записи:

```
WaveStream := TMemoryStream.Create;  
WaveStream.Position := 0;
with WaveHdr do
begin
  riff := 'RIFF';
  len := 36;
  cWavFmt := 'WAVEfmt ';
  dwHdrLen := 16;
  wFormat := 1;
  wNumChannels := 2;
  dwSampleRate := 44100;
  wBlockAlign := 4;
  dwBytesPerSec := 176400;
  wBitsPerSample := 16;
  cData := 'data';
  dwDataLen := 0;
end;
// Запись заголовка в поток
WaveStream.Write(WaveHdr, SizeOf(WAVHDR));
//Собственно запись
rchan := BASS_RecordStart(44100, 2, 0, @RecordingCallback, nil);
```

Функция обратного вызова при записи стандартная:

```
function RecordingCallback(Handle: HRECORD; buffer: Pointer; length: DWord;
  user: Pointer): boolean; stdcall;
begin
  Main.WaveStream.Write(buffer^, length);
  Result := True;
end;
```

Сохраняю в файл следующим образом:

```
WaveStream.SaveToFile('test.wav');
```

При использовании `TFileStream` результат тот же.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А другие/сторонние wav воспроизводятся?

Comment: Может после окончания записи нужно в хедере правильный размер данных указать? У вас же `dwDataLen := 0`

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, спасибо. Как оказалось, проблема именно в этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем разобрался.

Нужно после завершения записи внести информацию о продолжительности. Другое дело, что это оказывается почему-то не критично для потока.

На всякий случай выложу результат. Вдруг кому-то пригодится.

```
WaveStream.Position := 4;
i := w.Size - 8;
WaveStream.Write(i, 4);
i := i - $24;
WaveStream.Position := 40;
WaveStream.Write(i, 4);
WaveStream.SaveToFile('test.wav');
```

Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся.